# Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button"}

Tags: python, selenium

So im Trying to make a discord bot that sends news from selected news services, and Ive got it working on every website, except *Bild.de*. They have got a banner you have to accept before accesing the website, and I cant get past that. Like I said, I had no problems on any other website, but this one.

My code (python):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


# selenium part
url = 'https://www.bild.de/home/newsticker/news/alle-news-54190636.bild.html'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

#trying to accept cookie banner
browser.find_element_by_xpath(
"/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button").click()
```

Error Message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to be noted down here.

1. `Cookies` button is in `iframe`, so first we have to switch to `iframe` in Selenium.
2. I am using execute script to click on it.
3. Remember to switch back to default content when you are done with the iframe.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.bild.de/home/newsticker/news/alle-news-54190636.bild.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='SP Consent Message']")))
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.message-component.message-row.mobile-reverse>div:nth-child(2)>button")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I just noticed how little I know about selenium and web developement. Thank you for help!